# solrcloud plugin deployment

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am going to migrate our app from Lucene 4.7 to Solr 4.7 (in cloud).
As we have some custom analysers I am interested in how complicated is deployment process with Solr Cloud.
Exactly how does it looks like with custom analysers.
I couldn't find any specific information, can anybody help me?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you have the jars present on the hosts and inside the solr jvm classpath (or specified in the solr config as presented here : http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml) then it should not be harder than specifying the field definitions along with your custom analyzers inside the schema file

Comment: but is there any manner to let Solr propagate jars by itself? I saw entry 'sharedLib' in the config but I am not sure if it is what I want